# Tengo un problema con mi archivo para guardar los datos de un formulario en mi base de datos xampp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un archivo para guardar los datos puestos en un formulario hacia una base de datos xampp y me aparece un error, el cual es:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "values", expecting ")" in (la ruta del archivo) on line 13

```
<?php
session_start();
include("nomina2.php");
$empleado=$_POST["empleado"];
$sueldo_basico=$_POST["sueldo_basico"];
$auxilio_transporte=$_POST["auxilio_transporte"];
$horas_extras=$_POST["horas_extras"];
$total_devengado=$_POST["total_devengado"];
$eps=$_POST["eps"];
$pension=$_POST["pension"];
$total_deducido=$_POST["total_deducido"];
$total_pagar=$_POST["total_pagar"];
$guardar=$conexion->prepare('insert into nomina (empleado,sueldo_basico,auxilio_transporte,horas_extras,total_devengado,eps,pension,total_deducido,total_pagar):'values)(':empleado,:sueldo_basico,:auxilio_transporte,:horas_extras,:total_devengado,:eps,:pension,:total_deducido,:total_pagar');
$guardar=bindParam(':empleado',$empleado);
$guardar=bindParam(':sueldo_basico',$sueldo_basico);
$guardar=bindParam(':auxilio_transporte',$auxilio_transporte);
$guardar=bindParam(':horas_extras',$horas_extras);
$guardar=bindParam(':total_devengado',$total_devengado);
$guardar=bindParam(':eps',$eps);
$guardar=bindParam(':pension',$pension);
$guardar=bindParam(':total_deducido',$total_deducido);
$guardar=bindParam(':total_pagar',$total_pagar);
$guardar->execute();
$resultado=$conexion->lastInsertId();
echo $resultado;
?>
```

Si necesitan el archivo de la conexion o del formulario para ayudarme, diganme.

El formulario esta hecho en html.

Comment: Tienes errores tipográficos aquí: `,total_pagar):'values)(':empleado,`... mira de ponerlo así; `,total_pagar) values(:empleado,` (quitándole esos dos puntos y los apóstrofes que aparecen dentro de **values()**)
`

Comment: Considera poner tu consulta entre comillas dobles, así, en el interior, podrás usar comillas simples donde lo requieras, además de eso, no estás abriendo y cerrando bien los paréntesis. Así debería funcionar: **`"insert into nomina (empleado,sueldo_basico,auxilio_transporte,horas_extras,total_devengado,eps,pension,total_deducido,total_pagar) values (':empleado,:sueldo_basico,:auxilio_transporte,:horas_extras,:total_devengado,:eps,:pension,:total_deducido,:total_pagar'");`** Por otra parte, tu código está expuesto a casos de *`Undefined index`*, deberías verificar los `$_POST`.